# Apache: SSL and Non-SSL (without VirtualHosts?)

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, ssl, http, https

I have a web server and have two folders I would like to treat differently.

One folder on the local filesystem should use SSL and the other should not, for example:

```
/path/to/ssl/site
/path/to/nonssl/site
```

I have looked into `<Directory>` parameters but you cannot disable `SSLEngine` at that level.

```
[root@host /]# service httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd: Syntax error on line # of /some/config/file.conf:
SSLEngine not allowed here
```

It seems using `<VirtualHost>` gives that granularity but I would be using the same hostname and therefore I am a bit confused. (matching wildcard *)

```
# need to create a virtualhost for each Non-SSL folder?
<VirtualHost *:80>
  SSLDisable
  ...
  ...
</VirtualHost>

# need to create a virtualhost for each SSL folder?
<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine on
  ...
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Also, if I were to add and additional `<Directory>`, would it actually have to be a `<VirtualHost>`?

I know I am probably not understanding the abstractions of Apache and some of the concepts, but I find it difficult to know where to start.

If there is an alternative methodology, or a concept I am missing please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VirtualHost` is what you want to use to serve both HTTP and HTTPS and different content for each. If you have one listening on port 80 and the other on 443, then having the same name isn't an issue. You don't need to do `SSLDisable` on the `VirtualHost` on port 80.

You have one `VirtualHost` which handles the HTTPS traffic and another for HTTP traffic. You can serve different or the same content by setting the `DocumentRoot` option or using `Directory`, etc.

Comment: This worked. a combination of directory settings for `Options +Indexes` and `VirtualHost` for the specific port. Thank you.